# Use sort for multidimensional array (array in array) in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to know that how can we use `sort` or `sorted` function for multidimensional array in Swift?

For example theirs an array:

```
[
    [5, "test888"],
    [3, "test663"],
    [2, "test443"],
    [1, "test123"]
]
```

And I want to sort it via the first ID's low to high:

```
[
    [1, "test123"],
    [2, "test443"],
    [3, "test663"],
    [5, "test888"]
]
```

So how can we do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `sort`:

```
let sortedArray = arr.sort { ($0[0] as? Int) < ($1[0] as? Int) }
```

Result:

> [[1, test123], [2, test443], [3, test663], [5, test123]]

We optionally cast the parameter as an Int since the content of your arrays are AnyObject.

*Note: `sort` was previously named `sorted` in Swift 1.*

---

No problem if you declare the internal arrays as AnyObject, an empty one won't be inferred as an NSArray:

```
var arr = [[AnyObject]]()

let sortedArray1 = arr.sort { ($0[0] as? Int) < ($1[0] as? Int) }

print(sortedArray1) // []

arr = [[5, "test123"], [2, "test443"], [3, "test663"], [1, "test123"]]

let sortedArray2 = arr.sort { ($0[0] as? Int) < ($1[0] as? Int) }

print(sortedArray2)  // [[1, test123], [2, test443], [3, test663], [5, test123]]
```

Comment: Be careful, this has changed again in Swift 3, where `sort` is the mutating method, and `sorted` is the one returning a new array...

Answer (score 7):

**Update for Swift 5.0**

sort function is renamed to sorted. Here is the new syntax

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted(by: {$0[0] < $1[0] })
```

Unlike "sort" function in <= swift4.0, sort function doesn't modify elements in array. Instead, it just returns a new array.

example,

```
let array : [(Int, String)] = [
    (5, "test123"),
    (2, "test443"),
    (3, "test663"),
    (1, "test123")
]

let sorted = array.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
print(sorted)
print(array)


Output:
[(1, "test123"), (2, "test443"), (3, "test663"), (5, "test123")]

[(5, "test123"), (2, "test443"), (3, "test663"), (1, "test123")]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use an array of tuples, then you won't have any problems with type casts:

```
let array : [(Int, String)] = [
    (5, "test123"),
    (2, "test443"),
    (3, "test663"),
    (1, "test123")
]

let sortedArray = array.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

Swift is all about type safety

(Change `sorted` to `sort` if you're using Swift 2.0)

Comment: OK, this code is working fine. And I also want to ask that how can we use sorted to sort NSDate (from present to past) ? :)

Answer (score 0):

in Swift 3,4 you should use "Compare". for example:

```
let sortedArray.sort { (($0[0]).compare($1[0]))! == .orderedDescending }
```